# Nodemon with ts-node express server: app crashed

Tags: node.js, nodemon, ts-node

I'm trying to build an express server with an angular 5 client. I'm using "ts-node" and "nodemon" and "ng build --watch" all together in one "dev" script so they can all automatically compile together. Every other time the app changes, nodemon says the app crashes. If I remove the line app.listen it will work every time without any errors.

package.json script:

```
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"nodemon --config ./servernodemon.json\" \"ng build --watch\"",
```

servernodemon.json:

```
{
    "delay": "500",
    "ignore": ["servernm/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "verbose": true,
    "exec": "ts-node server/server.app.ts",
    "watch": ["server"],
    "ext": "ts"
}
```

server.app.ts:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import * as express from 'express';
const path = require('path');

console.log('Revving up server');

const app: express.Express = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist-site')));

app.get('/*', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist-site/index.html'));
});

console.log('Starting server');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3005;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}!`)
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Failed to start server', err);
});
```

Console output after 3 changes and initial run:

```
$ npm run dev

> project@0.0.0 dev /Users/project
> concurrently --kill-others "nodemon --config ./servernodemon.json" "ng build --watch"

[0] [nodemon] 1.13.2
[0] [nodemon] reading config /Users/project/servernodemon.json
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 40641 to restart
[0] [nodemon] ignoring: /Users/project/.git/**/* .nyc_output .sass-cache bower_components coverage /Users/project/node_modules/**/* server/**/*.spec.ts
[0] [nodemon] watching: /Users/project/server/**/*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[0] [nodemon] starting `ts-node server/server.app.ts`
[0] [nodemon] child pid: 40644
[0] [nodemon] watching 2 files
[0] Revving up server
[0] Starting server
[0] Server listening on port 3005!
[0] [nodemon] files triggering change check: server/server.app.ts
[0] [nodemon] matched rule: **/Users/codybrooks/project/server/**/*
[0] [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1
[0] [nodemon] delaying restart for 500ms
[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] server/server.app.ts
[0] 
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] Date: 2017-12-16T16:14:02.235Z
[1] Hash: b5d642e77abf8ebb4d1a
[1] Time: 6247ms
[1] chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
[1] chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 7.77 kB [initial] [rendered]
[1] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 199 kB [initial] [rendered]
[1] chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
[1] chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.33 MB [initial] [rendered]
[0] [nodemon] files triggering change check: server/server.app.ts
[0] [nodemon] matched rule: **/Users/project/server/**/*
[0] [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1
[0] [nodemon] delaying restart for 500ms
[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] server/server.app.ts
[0] 
[0] [nodemon] starting `ts-node server/server.app.ts`
[0] [nodemon] child pid: 40656
[0] Revving up server3
[0] Starting server
[0] Server listening on port 3005!
[0] [nodemon] files triggering change check: server/server.app.ts
[0] [nodemon] matched rule: **/Users/project/server/**/*
[0] [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1
[0] [nodemon] delaying restart for 500ms
[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] server/server.app.ts
[0] 
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Versions of packages:

```
"concurrently": "^3.5.1",
"nodemon": "^1.13.2",
"tslint": "^5.7.0",
```

Comment: What is odd though, if I recreate the project, it doesn't happen immediately. Over several times of running the dev command (stopping and re-running it) I see the issue return.

Comment: Update: It appears the issuer is stemming from using concurrently. The issue does not happen when I'm not using concurrently. I changed the script to no longer use concurrently, but instead use the "|" separator. Unfortunately this also means my solution won't work on Windows machines. :(